# i can not understand why my code is not being executed

Tags: javascript, html

I have three buttons below and the button marked `+1`, should increment wallet by one. The button marked `Transfer money to Bank` should move wallet amount to bank and reset wallet to 0. But, nothing is being called or working. I am absolutely stuck. Please help.

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Area 52</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1><center>Area 52</center></h1>
      <p><center><p Id="name">User</p><p>Is currently logged on</p></center><p>
    <script>
      var money=0
      var bank=0
      var Money_handler(money,bank,op){
        alert("!")
        if (op=="add"){
          money+=1
          document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = money;
          return money;
        }
        if (op=="bank"){
          bank=bank+money
          document.getElementById('bank').innerHTML = bank;
          money=0
          document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = money;
          return money
        }

      }
      var namer=function(){
        var x=prompt("What is your name?");
        document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = x;
      }
        </script>
    <center>
      <button type="button" onclick=money=Money_handler(money,bank,"add")>+1</button>
      <button type="button" onclick=namer()>Enter username</button>
      <button type="button" onclick=Money_handler(money,bank,"bank")>Transfer money to Bank</button>
      <p Id="wallet">Wallet: $0</p>
      <p Id="bank">Bank: $0</p>
    </center>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors and missing semi-colons etc. A good place to start is to use your browser's javascript console and it will show you many of those problems. You should also switch to a text editor made for writing JS, it will  highlight syntax problems for you.

Comment: Look at your browser's error console.  The code has multiple syntax errors.

Comment: `var Money_handler(money,bank,op){`…`}` is invalid. Use the [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read the errors. Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You just use a var instead of a function:

```
function Money_handler(money,bank,op){
```

**EDIT:**
When you update the money you forget the rest of the line:

```
.innerHTML = "Wallet: $"+money;
```

You had to change this at all 3 places with wallet/bank.

Comment: ah, lol i've been so caught up with other parts of the code i completely forgot to add the function part, cheers!

Comment: If you want to use `var`, you could also do` var money_handler = function(money, bank, op) { ... }` Or you could also use the new lambda functions: `var money_handler = (money, bank, op) => { ... }` Your choice.

Comment: i was aware of this change i did not bother with putting it in until i could fix the original problem

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Aside from the function keyword, you also missed quotes for the onclick attribute value.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Area 52</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1><center>Area 52</center></h1>
  <p><center><p Id="name">User</p><p>Is currently logged on</p></center><p>
<script>
 var money = 0
 var bank = 0
 var Money_handler= function(money, bank, op) {
  alert("!")
  if (op == "add") {
    money += 1
    document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = money;
    return money;
  }
  if (op == "bank") {
    bank = bank + money
    document.getElementById('bank').innerHTML = bank;
    money = 0
    document.getElementById('wallet').innerHTML = money;
    return money
  }

 }
 var namer = function() {
  var x = prompt("What is your name?");
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = x;
 }
</script>
<center>
  <button type="button" onclick="Money_handler(money,bank,'add');">+1</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="namer()">Enter username</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="Money_handler(money,bank,'bank')">Transfer money to Bank</button>
  <p Id="wallet">Wallet: $0</p>
  <p Id="bank">Bank: $0</p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I only corrected the syntactical flaws. I think you should work on logic.